# Excel to Word Macro

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a macro(similar to the following) connected to an image in an excel worksheet.  When I click it, it takes all the necessary information from one worksheet to a TPS Report worksheet and then saves the document as a word file with the name being whatever is present in cell B5.  It works fine, except the problem is anytime I click to start the macro it regenerates every single word document for each line of the worksheet.  Is there a way I can get it to only generate the newest documents?   So, if files  "A" ,"B", and "C"  have already been created, but there's data on the worksheet up to "F", when I click the macro it only creates "D", "E", and "F" instead of ABCDE and F.  I could not find the answer to this on here and any help would be appreciated.  Is there a way i can add some code after the Save as Command that checks to see if the file exists and only creates it if it does not exist in the directory.

```
Sub ControlWordTPS()
    Dim appWD As Word.Application
    Set appWD = CreateObject("Word.Application.8")
    appWD.Visible = True
    Sheets("TPS").Select
    'Find the last row with data in the database
    FinalRow = Range("P9999").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 5 To FinalRow
        Sheets("TPS").Select
        Range("A" & i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("TPSForm").Range("B5")
        Range("D" & i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("TPSForm").Range("B6")
        Range("E" & i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("TPSForm").Range("B7")
        Range("G" & i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("TPSForm").Range("B8")
        Range("M" & i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("TPSForm").Range("B9")
        Range("N" & i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("TPSForm").Range("B10")
        Range("O" & i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("TPSForm").Range("B11")
        Range("H" & i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("TPSForm").Range("B24")
        Range("I" & i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("TPSForm").Range("B25")
        Range("K" & i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("TPSForm").Range("B26")
        Range("J" & i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("TPSForm").Range("B27")
        Sheets("TPSForm").Select
        Range("A1:F28").Copy
        appWD.Documents.Add
        appWD.Selection.Paste
        appWD.ActiveDocument.SaveAs Filename:="G:\Warranties\Customer\2014\2014TPSForms        \TPSAUTO\" & Range("B5")
        appWD.ActiveDocument.Close
    Next i
    appWD.Quit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the For loop; instead copy all rows at once, like shown in the following code snippet:

```
' Copy multiple rows at once
Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows("5:" & FinalRow).Copy

' Create a new Word document
appWD.Documents.Add

' Paste the contents of the clipboard into the new Word document
appWD.Selection.Paste
```

' ... the rest of your code saving Word doc

Regards,